# is this systems broadcast ordered or normal broadcast?

Tags: android, broadcast

I'm trying to figure out if a system event broadcast is broadcasted 
using ordered broadcast or normal.. 
The event is EVENT_REMINDER and in the source for the calendarprovider 
i noticed it sets up a alarmmanager to sent the broadcast.

I can't find how the alarmmanager sends it. 
My guess would be as a normal broadcast , 
But while i was trying some things i noticed i could delay the 
system's notification (tried up to 10 sec) by building a sleep in my 
broadcastreceiver. 
This would indicate that they are handled ordered , and the systems 
receiver is only called when mine has finished.

But can i be sure of this behavour?? (in all 1.5> sdk versions) 
the docs state that in some cases normal broadcasts are also handled 
ordered..due to spare of resources.

All thoughts on this are welcome.... 
Thanks , arnold

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the isOrderedBroadcast flag in the BroadcastReceiver.